# Use two gear racks to multiply linear motion

Tags: gears

I have an object (shown in green) that I want to pull out distance X and then I want another object (shown in red) to move 2X. What would be the best way to achieve this?  I thought that gear racks connected to each and then linked by a gear train might work, but I can't quite figure out the best way to lay that out (or if there is a simpler way to do this).

[image: Objects moving]

Comment: Do you want both objects to move simultaneously or one after the other?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to gears is to use a parallelogram mechanism, much like a Pantograph. All you need to do is have 2 parallelograms on top of each other the other with 2 times as long edges while sharing the 2 of the edges.

**Note** if you allready have an vertical slider then you can simplify the mechanism to 2 cranks essentially eliminating 3 of 6 parts. Though the gear has less parts

[image]

**Image 1**: A conceptual sketch of a parallelogram methanism

You have quite a leeway on designing a longer vs wider parallelogram. Even vary the relative speed profile if you so wish. Even though *image 1* shows the front most item moving more you can shift the link down wherever you want. Or you can hinge the thing upside down or search a inversion alternate config of this mechanism.

You can also do similar things with a *Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage* or a Chebyshev's Lambda Mechanism if you wish. But tehy are more involved.

Answer (score 1):

On the toothed gear track have gears (cogs) where one is twice the diameter of the other : with the same rotational input the larger one will move twice the distance...

Answer (score 1):

Make one rack static connect a rack parallel to that connected to object X2 and add a gear sandwiched between them with the axle connected to object X.

That way as object X moves the other object X2 will move twice as far.